# Crystal in temperature controlled environment vs OCXO

Tags: oscillator, temperature

Are there any studies on the performance of crystal oscillators in temperature controlled environments vs an OCXO? I mean do you control just the temperature in OCXO, or do you need to account for other factors e.g. Pressure, humidity etc.

Comment: Does an Oven-Controlled-Crystal-Oscillator (OCXO) differ from a temperature-controlled-crystal-oscillator? Not in my mind. Temp control is just that: a controlled temperature environment. Temperature-compensated-XO is a different case, usually for less critical applications.

Comment: @glen_geek Long-term aging compared to a good TCXO can be similar (a few ppm for 10-20 years) but short term stability can be much better with OCXOs.

Comment: TCXO can use less power than OCXO but can be more difficult to design. Double OCXO have very good stability and are very reasonably priced on line (used).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only temperature is actively controlled. Usually OCXO and XO (and TCXO) units are hermetically sealed so humidity is not a factor.

All oscillators and crystals are designed to have little effect from barometric pressure changes and forces on the leads.

Edit:
@Enerwal makes a good point about the crystal cut. Apparently SC ("stress compensated") cut crystals are most used for OCXOs, as well as IT cut. [Here](http://www.conwin.com/pdfs/at_or_sc_for_ocxo.pdf) is a comparison of the SC cut against the AT cut more commonly used for non-ovenized oscillators. From [this](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/AT-cut-vs-SC-cut-quartz-crystal.html) source is a comparison of the temperature sensitivities (graph below) but there are other important differences such as aging and drive sensitivity and pressure sensitivity.

[image]

They appear to be better in many regards, but have an unwanted oscillation mode that needs to be suppressed by the circuitry, require vacuum in the cavity and are generally more fussy and labor intensive to produce, thus more expensive. They are less pullable (higher Q), which means they have to be trimmed to a tighter tolerance.

Of course aging is accentuated in OCXOs that have an high internal operating temperature.

Comment: +1 for mentioning SC cut. In my opinion, the higher Q is the primary advantage.

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, the crystals used in OCXO are selected for a temperature characteristic that makes them more stable at oven temperatures, .vs. using a a standard crystal that you build your own oven around, which is typically aimed at being fairly stable at "room temperature"

Ovenized crystals are aimed to be most stable at a temperature that's reliably above the outside (operating) temperature of the unit, since they do not normally include cooling - the only way they can heat to a stable temperature is if that temperature is always above the temperature outside the oven.

Here is a link I won't plagiarize that gets into more detail...
http://leapsecond.com/hpan/an200-2.pdf